# How to convert JSON to Spark schema automatically?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a big JSON which is want to use in Spark Structured Streaming. I don't want to re-type this JSON as Spark schema expression manually. Can I do this automatically once?

---

I wrote this

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Infer Schema") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark \
    .read \
    .option("multiline", True) \
    .json("file_examples/dataflow/row01.json")

df.printSchema()

df.show()

with open("dataflow_schema.json", "w") as fp:
    fp.write(df.schema.json())
```

Is this ok?

Comment: I've added an example with some kafka notes, let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path. You may save your schema as a json and then load it later. Be sure to convert it to `json` and then a `StructType` before use

```py
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

with open("dataflow_schema.json", "r") as fp:
    json_schema_str = fp.read()
    my_schema = StructType.fromJson(json.loads(json_schema_str))
```

In your structured streaming query if you have a `json` column you may use the [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) method to convert your json to a `struct` type and eventually several columns eg:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json,col

# Assume that we have a kafkaStream
kafkaStream.selectExpr("CAST(value as string)")\
           .select(from_json(col("value"),my_schema).alias("json_value"))\
           .selectExpr("json_value.*") # extract as columns
```

Comment: Thanks! I came to close approach, but all parsed values appear to be `null`. With no error messages.